# ILMerge - use wildcard and specify main assembly

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge

I have main assembly `MyAssembly.dll` and a lot of libraries which I want to merge into main assembly. Because there are lots of them, I wanted to include them all using wildcard, something like this:

`ILMerge.exe /wildcard /allowDup /out:MyAssembly.Merged.dll MyAssembly.dll *.dll`

The problem with this approach is that it merges `MyAssembly.dll` twice, resulting in duplicated type names, so need to use `/allowDup` option. But this option renames duplicated types, and I don't want that (my DLL is a plugin for other application and all types must have original names).
I could omit `MyAssembly.dll` in command line, but because ILMerge merges assemblies alphabetically, it treats the first one as a main assembly (for example `Autofac.dll`) which results in final assembly having wrong metadata (version etc.).
Is it possible to exclude certain assembly name with wildcard option?

Comment: Idk but maybe try putting them in a different folder from the main assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to exclude certain assembly name with wildcard option?

No. You could write a batch file that builds the command line though, using `for` for example. You could also write a script in another language.

However `ilmerge` is an artefact of the past and it has a whole slew of problems. Since it copies the code into one assembly it changes how run-time loading works, which can easily break lazy-loaded programs like WPF or ASP.NET Core.

Nowadays we have .Net5 which provides first-class support for single-assembly binaries, both that run under the installed environment (like your assembly used to need) or self-contained (it includes the .net5 runtime as well). It doesn't mash together the code into one assembly, it sticks to separate assemblies loaded at run-time directly from your generated large "assembly", so your actual code doesn't change.

Comment: I've been thinking about building command line using script, but I was looking for simplier solution. Well that's a shame ILMerge doesn't support that. 
I know ILMerge isn't perfect, but I have to use it to deal with DLL-Hell in plugin ecosystem (other plugin may use different version of some library I'm using and causing issues).

Comment: No you don't, you can just use .net5 as I said.

Comment: No, I can't use dotnet5. As I said I'm developing plugin and the host application doesn't support dotnet core. Trust me, I wish I could use dotnet5 :)